# Getting the wrong output from function in R

Tags: r, function, dataframe, combinations

I have the function below:

```
Proposed <- function(N_b,Lanes,m,A,x.sqr,e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5,S,a,b) {
  e <- data.frame(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5)
  CSi <- m * ((Lanes/N_b) + (A * (combn(e,Lanes,sum)) / x.sqr) * (b*S^a))
  return(max(CSi))
}
```

When I apply it to my sample row of data:

```
> DATA[1, ]
  Lanes N_b N_l   A x.sqr  e_1 e_2  e_3   e_4 e_5  S Proposed.Girder1  UG       CSi    m
1     3   5   4 -12  1440 21.8 9.8 -2.2 -14.2   0 12        0.6261667 100 0.5918969 0.85
```

With:

```
x <- DATA[1, ]
Proposed1(x[["N_b"]], x[["Lanes"]], x[["m"]], x[["A"]], x[["x.sqr"]], x[["e_1"]], x[["e_2"]], 
        x[["e_3"]], x[["e_4"]], x[["e_5"]],x[["S"]], a = 0.01, b = 0.5)

# [1] 0.5695447
```

I get the correct answer. But If I change the code to

```
Proposed2 <- function(N_b,Lanes,m,A,x.sqr,e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5,S,a,b) {
  e <- data.frame(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5)
  CSi <- m * ((Lanes/N_b) + (A * max(combn(e,Lanes,sum)) / x.sqr) * (b*S^a))
  return(CSi)
}
```

which I anticipated that would have the same outcome, I get the wrong answer:

```
Proposed2(x[["N_b"]], x[["Lanes"]], x[["m"]], x[["A"]], x[["x.sqr"]], x[["e_1"]], x[["e_2"]], 
        x[["e_3"]], x[["e_4"]], x[["e_5"]],x[["S"]], a = 0.01, b = 0.5)

# [1] 0.3952675
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `A` is negative, the function is maximised when `combn(e,Lanes,sum)` is minimised.

```
x <- readr::read_table2("
 Lanes N_b N_l   A x.sqr  e_1 e_2  e_3   e_4 e_5  S Proposed.Girder1  UG       CSi    m
3   5   4 -12  1440 21.8 9.8 -2.2 -14.2   0 12        0.6261667 100 0.5918969 0.85
")

Proposed3 <- function(N_b,Lanes,m,A,x.sqr,e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5,S,a,b) {
  e <- data.frame(e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4,e_5)
  # Note "min"
  CSi <- m * ((Lanes/N_b) + (A * min(combn(e,Lanes,sum)) / x.sqr) * (b*S^a))
  return(CSi)
}

Proposed3(x[["N_b"]], x[["Lanes"]], x[["m"]], x[["A"]], x[["x.sqr"]], x[["e_1"]], x[["e_2"]], 
        x[["e_3"]], x[["e_4"]], x[["e_5"]],x[["S"]], a = 0.01, b = 0.5)
#> [1] 0.5695447
```